# Patterns not matched: (_:_:_)

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, guard-clause

So I'm trying to build a function that takes a list of tuples and finds the tuple with the biggest second element. But I'm getting a pattern match error.

This is my code.

```
    resultTuple :: [((Int,Int),Int)] -> (Int,Int)
    resultTuple [] = error "something wrong"
    resultTuple [x] = fst(x)
    resultTuple (x:y:xs)
        | snd(x) >= snd(y) = resultTuple(x:xs)
        | snd(x) < snd(y) = resultTuple(y:xs)
```

This is my error.

```
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘resultTuple’: Patterns not matched: (_:_:_)
```

Comment: I suspect this is wrong, but maybe that guard needs a final case (maybe just `| _ = error "something wrong"`)? I think it looks like a complete set of patterns so I'm confused myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All your cases for `x:y:xs` have a condition and the compiler is warning you that you didn't cover the case where all the conditions are false. That is, the compiler is warning about the case where both `snd x >= snd y` and `snd x < snd y` are false.

Of course that can't actually happen, but the compiler does not realize that. To get rid of the warning, you can just replace the second condition with `otherwise`.

Comment: It can actually happen if someone implements `Ord` improperly. For example, `Ord Double` is implemented in a way that makes `nan >= nan` and `nan < nan` both `False`. (Of course it can't happen in this specific case because `snd x :: Int`, but the compiler doesn't take that into account.)